# What is the point of hg incoming?

Tags: mercurial

According to Mercurial's help page, hg incoming (and the "check for incoming changes" button in tortoiseHG does:

> "Show new changesets found in the specified path/URL or the default
>   pull location. These are the changesets that would have been pulled by
>   'hg pull' at the time you issued this command."

My question is: *What is the point of this behavior?* In what situation would I want to not just pull? If I wanted to see what changesets were pulled, I could just look at the log.

Have I been using mercurial wrong my whole life?

Comment: Does incoming use less bandwidth? Maybe on a slow connection (particularly 10+ years ago when hg was created) that could be valuable.

Answer (score 4):

There are various scenarios in which it can be useful. I'm just listing down my use cases hre.

a) I do `hg incom` to make sure I can pull and get ready to rebase my commits if there is anything on the remote.

b) I use `hg log -G` followed by `hg incom` quite often when doing offline peer review to make sure I don't pollute my repo and to know which rev to strip (if required) after the pull. FWIW, as a result of `hg incom` I have asked people to change their commit message even without pulling their changes for review.